# Is this basic file upload check secure enough?

Tags: php, file-upload

The mimetype is also being checked, but since that can be spoofed, is this additional simple snippet adequate for checking the validity of an uploaded file?

```
$safe_to_move = false;

$ext = array("pdf", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx");
if (in_array(preg_replace('/.*\./', '', strtolower($_FILES['file']['name'])), $ext)) {
    $safe_to_move = true;
}

if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    $safe_to_move = false;
}
```

Comment: under some circumstances yes, under other, no.

Comment: Yea it really depends on what you mean by "secure enough". If you mean "secure enough to prevent other file types being uploaded" then yes.

Comment: At the end of the day, you can't really confirm a file is what you think it is without knowing the internal file format and checking that etc...

Comment: @Spooler the main object is to ensure that a .php or .htaccess fie cannot be uploaded, I guess i'm wandering if it might be possible to craft some clever file name to get around the regular expression

Comment: @LukePark I agree with the logic but a .xls file containing `<?php unlink('../index.php')?>` couldn't actually be executed, or could it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is a solid approach but how secure it is depends more on how your server environment is set up.

This article offers some pretty good insight into what you're asking and everything i'm saying will more or less be a reference to it.
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/file-upload-vulnerabilities/

You've definitely done the right thing creating a white-list but...

> The most important thing is to keep uploaded files in a location that can’t access though
>   the Internet. This can be done either by storing uploaded files outside of the web root or configuring the web server to deny access to the uploads directory.

There's other things you can do to increase security and I totally advise you look at the solutions section of the linked article, but making sure those files are stored in a way that they can't easily be accessed "off site" makes it much harder to run them externally (obviously).

Tl;Dr
What you've done is a good first step and if your server environment is set up correctly it should be enough.

Comment: Not a problem, I always like to try and find a solid source when I answer a question :). Hope it helped !